# next.js client side component is getting updated too late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I have this [id] component in next.js, which is getting its content based on pathname, I had it in react.js but I have to write it in next.js , am generating metadata in layout.js and this is my client side page.js component(am using APP directory):

```
const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined'
   const [locationChange , setLocationChange] = useState( window.location.pathname)
   
  //const id = 
  const [id, setId] = useState((window.location.pathname).substring(1))
  // const [id, setId] = useState(isClient && (window.location.pathname).substring(1))
   //console.log(id)

  const [api, setApi] = useState({})

  const [parent, setParent] = useState()
  const [istoriebi, setIstoriebi] = useState({})
  const [prescentri, setPrescentri] = useState({})
  const [exactParent, setExactParent] = useState([])
  const [itself, setItself] = useState([])
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(10)
  const language = 1;
  const ref = useRef(null)


   console.log(id)
  useEffect(() => {
    const link = 'https://mywebsite.com/api/site_menu1.php';
    fetch(link)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        
        setPrescentri(data.menu)
        Object.entries(data.menu).map((item, index) => {
          //console.log(item[1])
           
          if (id && item[1].slug == id) {
            console.log(item[1])
            setApi(item[1].content_id)
            setParent(item[1].parent_id)

             console.log('aqamde2')
            const apiLink = `https://mywebssite.gov.ge/api/get_content.php?content_id=${item[1].content_id}`
            fetch(apiLink)
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((dat) => {
                setIstoriebi(dat)
                Object.entries(data.menu).map((qveitem, index) => {
                  if (qveitem[1].cat_id == item[1].parent_id) {
                      console.log('აქამდე3')
                    setExactParent(qveitem)
                    setItself(item)
                  }
                })
              })
          }

        })
      
      });

  }, [id , locationChange])
```

problem is that states are getting updated too late(1 update later), by that I mean that if I am currently at page 1 , and I go to page 2, content of page 2 is still of page 1, and after that if I go to page 3 , content of it is page 2;
I tried a lot of things but I can not find solution yet, any ideas?

Comment: You can show a loader each time page number is changed and hide the loader when the API gets all the data and set in the states.

Comment: its not about seconds,  state is 1 step back from the actual state every time

Comment: You can use next js router instead of window.location and pass that router in useEffect array depdency, that next js router is an object and will give you the dynamic route value.

Comment: when I use next js router , it throws error (router did not mount) that  router should only be used in ROUTER component a